# Optional PreBuildEvent in MSBuild?

Tags: build, msbuild, xbuild

Is it possible to have an optional `<PreBuildEvent>` in a `*.csproj` file? I have the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PreBuildEvent>git rev-parse HEAD &gt;../../git-hash.txt</PreBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This outputs the latest git hash to a file, which is embedded in the executable elsewhere.

Since I'm a University student, I'm often writing code on the University machines (and not my linux machine at home) which have SVN and not git, causing the build process to fail. Is  it possible to make the above `<PreBuildEvent />` optional so that if git isn't installed the build process doesn't fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just skipping the build event would leave you with an empty git-hash.txt so that doesn't seem the best idea. Instead you could just try to run the git command, and if it fails write a dummy hash to the file. I don't know the command line syntax to do that (a `PreBuildEvent` runs under cmd.exe) so here's an msbuild solution. Because of the `BeforeTargets="Build"` it will run before the build as well.

```
<Target Name="WriteGitHash" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="git --work-tree=$(Repo) --git-dir=$(Repo)\.git rev-parse HEAD 2> NUL" ConsoleToMSBuild="true" IgnoreExitCode="True">
    <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="GitTag" />
  </Exec>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GitTag Condition="'$(GitTag)' == ''">unknown</GitTag>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <WriteLinesToFile File="$(Repo)\git-hash.txt" Lines="$(GitTag)" Overwrite="True"/>
</Target>
```

Some notes:

- The `2> NUL` redirects standard error to the output so `GitTag` will be empty in case of an error, in which case it's set to 'unknown'
- Relying on the current directory is nearly always a bad idea so specify the directory to run git in explicitly in a property
- Same for the output file

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the `$(Repo)` variable a built-in?

Comment: No, sorry should have been more clear. It's a property you have to define yourself and have it point to the git repository. If that happens to be the directory which has the project file you can just use $(ProjectDir) for instance.

Comment: Ah right. Since my solution directory (`$(SolutionDir)` I think?) is the root of the git repository, I'll just use that then. This method looks a lot better than the one I was using :)

Comment: yes, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx for common properties